# PyGame not drawing rectangle

Tags: python, pygame

pygame not working
pygame is not drawing any rectangles or any other shapes all I see is a white and blank screen, and for people wondering yeah I have pygame installed

I am new to oop programming.
first) main.py
second) setting.py

```
from setting import *
import pygame


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def game(self):
        pygame.init()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        running = True
        x=0
        y=0
        for row in MAP:
                print(row)
                for pos in row:
                    print(pos)
                    if pos == "x":    
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 0, 255], [x, y, 20, 20], 1)
                        x+=20
        while running:
            clock.tick(FPS)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
            
            screen.fill(COLOR)
            pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.quit()
        quit()


game = Game()
game.game()
```

second) setting.py

```
FPS = 60
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
COLOR = [255,255,255]
TITLE = 'test'


MAP = [['x', 'x', 'x','x','x', 'x', 'x','x','x', 'x', 'x','x']
      ,['x', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x']
      ,['x', ' ', ' ', 'P', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x']
      ,['x', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x']
      ,['x', 'x', 'x','x','x', 'x', 'x','x','x', 'x', 'x','x']
]
```

Comment: You're filling the screen with `COLOR` and not drawing anything else during your loop.

Comment: you draw a rect once. You're not drawing it every frame. You are filling the screen with `COLOR` every frame though. Move your rect drawing code into the actual `while running` game loop. For *each* and *every* displayed frame, you have to explicitly draw/render what you want to see in that fame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redraw the scene in each frame. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

```py
from setting import *
import pygame

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def game(self):
        pygame.init()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        running = True

        while running:
            # limit the frames per second
            clock.tick(FPS)

            # handle the events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
            
            # clear the display
            screen.fill(COLOR)

            # draw all objects in the scene
            for y, row in enumerate(MAP):
                for x, pos in enumerate(row):
                    if pos == "x":    
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 0, 255], [x*20, y*20, 20, 20], 1)

            # update the display
            pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.quit()
        quit()

game = Game()
game.game()
```

The definition of the map can be simplified:

```py
MAP = [
    'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'x          x',
    'x  p       x',
    'x          x',
    'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
]
```